# Show that, if $ a + bi$ is prime in $\mathbb{Z} [i]$, then $a - bi$ is prime in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Show that, if $ a + bi$ is prime in $\mathbb{Z} [i]$, then $a - bi $ is prime in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$

Since $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is $ED$, then if $a+bi$ is irreducible then $a+bi$ is prime.
But now how I can relate $a+bi$ with $a-bi$?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $a-bi$ is not irreducible then take conjugate on both sides to obtain a contradiction.Conjugate of $a+bi$ is $a-bi$. So if $a-ib=(p+iq)(r+is)$ then clearly $a+ib=(p-iq)(r-is)$.

Comment: How connjecate on both side??

Comment: @Sara conjugate of $a+bi$ is $a-bi$. So if $a-ib=(p+iq)(r+is)$ then clearly $a+ib=(p-iq)(r-is)$. Hope this helps

Comment: @Sara This argument is also not complete for a similar reason as I mentioned on user26857's answer.

Answer (score 3):

In fact the property holds in every quadratic ring $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{d}]$ if one uses the definition of prime elements: say $a+b\sqrt{d}$ is prime, and want to show that $a-b\sqrt{d}$ is also prime.

Following a nitpick from the comments let's first show that $a-b\sqrt{d}$ is not invertible: suppose it is, and then there is $z\in\mathbb Z[\sqrt{d}]$ such that $(a-b\sqrt d)z=1$. From here we get $(a+b\sqrt d)\overline{z}=1$, so $a+b\sqrt d$ is invertible, a contradiction.

Now suppose $a-b\sqrt{d}\mid z_1z_2$ where $z_i\in\mathbb Z[\sqrt{d}]$. Then $a+b\sqrt{d}\mid\overline{z}_1\overline{z}_2$ where $\overline{z}_i$ is the conjugate of $z_i$. Since $a+b\sqrt{d}$ is prime it follows $a+b\sqrt{d}\mid\overline{z}_1$ or $a+b\sqrt{d}\mid\overline{z}_2$. Suppose $a+b\sqrt{d}\mid\overline{z}_1$. Then $a-b\sqrt{d}\mid z_1$ and we are done.

Comment: This is fantastic. Thanks user 26857

Comment: @Sara Beware, the above is not a complete proof. In addition to the above we also need to show that $\,a - b i\,$ is a (nonzero) nonunit in order to conclude that it is prime. Do you see how to do that?

Comment: @user26857 I have seen many proofs fail due to that (and analogous) oversights, so I thought it worthy of explicit mention (esp. at this level).

Comment: @BillDubuque AFAIK $(0)$ is a prime ideal in any integral domain, so $0$ is a prime element, or not?

Comment: @user26857 Depends on convention. That's why I wrote (nonzero) in parens. In any case, the main point is that one does need to prove that it is a *nonunit*, since units are never considered prime.