# Algebra. If $R$ is a commutative associative ring with neutral element.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Algebra. If $R$ is a commutative associative ring with neutral element. Then if R|P is an integral domain ($ab \in R|P \implies a=0 \ or \ b=0$) , then $1 \notin $ P ? This is the only thing I can deduct from another proof, is this correct , or must I search for another reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $1\in P$, then since $P$ is an ideal every multiple of $1$ is in $P$, meaning $P=R$. $R/R$ is the ring with one element, which apparently by convention is not an integral domain.

Comment: The zero ring is *not* a domain (by widespread convention).

Comment: But, by related convention $(1)$ is not considered prime, just like $1$ is not considered prime in $\,\Bbb Z.\ $ This is a common oversight, e.g. [see this recent answer.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1311625/show-that-if-a-bi-is-prime-in-mathbbz-i-then-a-bi-is-prime-in/1312040?noredirect=1#comment2683263_1312040)

Comment: A prime ideal is \emph{defined} to be a proper subset of the ring (with an additional property obviously).

Comment: Fine. Due to peer pressure I've changed my answer.

Comment: @Matt Are you aware of *any* author that considers units to be prime?

Comment: No. But a principal prime ideal need not be generated by a prime element. For example $(0)$ is prime in an integral domain.

Comment: @Matt Yes, that's mentioned in the comments in my link. Besides units, zero is the other exceptional case. While some authors *do* allow $\,0\,$ to be prime, I don't recall any authors ever allowing a unit to be prime.

Comment: Some of these conventions are discussed in other threads, e.g. see [Why doesn't 0 being a prime ideal in Z imply that 0 is a prime number?](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/3716/242).
and [Why 1 is not considered to be a prime number?,](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/5735/242)
and see John Conway's reason for considering $-1$ to be prime in [Is -1 prime?](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1175403/242)

Comment: @MattSamuel : I agree with Bill in this case. Prime ideals are explicitly defined to be *proper* ideals of $R$ in every text I know (which is a lot), no exceptions. Allowing the entire ring to be a prime ideal does not "fit" into the big scheme well. However, $R$ is allowed to be a *semiprime* ideal in the same texts.

Comment: I don't disagree. I haven't looked at a textbook that defines prime ideals in a long time.